# String Values Are Returned As Null | Custom Constructors and Setting Values

Tags: java, methods, constructor, null, return

I've created a simplified version of my current assignment for my programming course.

I've created a test program that asks the user for an input, studentName, studentName is then validated through another class. My end goal is to print out a method called toString() that holds the value the user has entered for the studentName. Right now my program returns null, not the value of studentName. The problem is I'm not sure how to properly set the values with a constructor.

If you could set up a proper constructor and a way to properly print the value the user has entered through the command prompt, I would appreciate it!

Here is the class that contains the main method. Note: I may have declared too many class objects because I was in a hurry.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestMcTest
{
  TestMcTest2 test3 = new TestMcTest2();
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
   TestMcTest test2 = new TestMcTest();
   TestMcTest2 test = new TestMcTest2();
   test2.getStudentInfo();

   System.out.println(test.toString());

  }



   public void getStudentInfo()
   {
    int valid = 0; 
    Scanner input =  new Scanner(System.in);
     do
     {
      System.out.println("Enter a name for a student");
      valid = test3.getStudentName(input.nextLine());
     }while(valid == 0);
   }
}
```

Here is the class that holds the validation and the toString() method that I want to call into the main method of the class with the main method.

```
public class TestMcTest2
{
  private String studentName;

  public String setStudentName()
  {
    return studentName;
  }

  public int getStudentName(String studentName)
  {
   int valid = 0;
   if (studentName.length() != 0)
   {
     valid = 1;
     this.studentName = studentName;
   }
   return valid;
  }


  public String toString()
  {
   return this.studentName;

  }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You dint set the value of variable `studentName` so the default value of string is printed i.e. `null`

In `TestMcTest` you have do

```
TestMcTest2 test = new TestMcTest2();
test.setStudentName("singhakash");

System.out.println(test.toString());
```

and in `TestMcTest2` change

```
 public void setStudentName(String studentName){

    this.studentName = studentName;
 }
```

this will give the expected output.

Btw your method name says opposite of its functionality.

Answer (score 0):

> If you could set up a proper constructor and a way to properly print
>   the value the user has entered through the command prompt, I would
>   appreciate it!

```
public class TestMcTest2{
   ....
   public TestMcTest2(String s){
    this.studentName = s;
   }
}
```

You have to use the newly constructor now like this:

```
TestMcTest2 test3 = new TestMcTest2("hot name");
```

And you can print it out like this after your `do-while`

```
System.out.println(test3.toString());
```

And I'm pretty sure you need the `@Override` annotation at the `toString()` method.

EDIT:

```
   @Override <- add this
     public String toString()
      {
       return this.studentName);

      }
```

Comment: The @Override annotation is not necessary - it depends on the compiler settings (however you should provide them).

Comment: It's printing out "TestMcTest2@5eef9f84" in the command prompt now?